# How to populate div-table from JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, html, css-tables

I'm new to JavaScript and wondering how to populate a div-table from a JavaScript array. The div-table looks as following:

```
<div id="palette" style="border: solid 1px black; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The array is one-dimensional and contains strings. Each string from array should be in particular cell in div-table.

Comment: Can you further exemplify how you would like the table to be populated and how the js array is structured?

Comment: The array is one-dimensional and contains strings. Each string from array goes to particular cell in div-table.

Comment: could you show us what did you come up with so far?

Comment: Only HTML above and CSS, which is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Javascript only (this might be easier using jQuery), here is what you can do:

- use the function `.getElementById()` to access the containing element
- use the function `.getElementsByClassName()` to access the subelements
- use the attribute `.innerText` to write into the selected elements.

Here is a working example of how to do it:

```js
var arr = ['Adam','Bruce','Clive','Don','Evan','Francis', 'Glenn', 'Henry', 'Ivan', 'Jade', 'Ken', 'Logan', 'Mario', 'Nathan', 'Omar', 'Quentin', 'Peter', 'Roman'];

var palette = document.getElementById("palette");

var rows = palette.getElementsByClassName("divTableRow");

var counter = 0;

for (var row of rows) {
  var cells = row.getElementsByClassName("divTableCell");
  for (var cell of cells) {
    cell.innerText = arr[counter];
    counter++;
  };
};
```

```css
#palette {
  border: none;
  display: table;
}

.divTableRow {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-row;
}

.divTableCell {
  width: 28%;
  padding: 1%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="palette" style="border: solid 1px black; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
        <div class="divTableCell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```